# Fetch Spreadsheet ID using Google Golang Sheets API V4 / Drive API V3?

Tags: go, google-sheets, drive

I'm using Golang for a small project of mine and am currently trying to pull a spreadsheet ID given the exactly filesystem path (in Drive) and spreadsheet/worksheet name. However, looking through the API library in Golang, I don't see a function that allows me to do this.

I'm pretty new to this kind of programming in general so sorry in advance if this has a trivial solution.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to use the drive api first to get the file by its name and then get that file's id which corresponds to the spreadsheet's id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `drive.files.list` in Drive API at Google. `drive.files.list` can search files with folder information from your Google Drive.

From your question, I thought following 2 steps.

1. Search file using `drive.files.list`. File ID and parent folder id can be retrieved, simultaneously. In this case, the fields are id and parents.
2. Retrieve folder name from folder id using `drive.files.get`. The field is name.

You can make file tree using folder information got from each file.

About sample script, it used Go Quickstart for Drive API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/go) Please change `main()` for a script of "Step 3: Set up the sample" to following script.

**Script :**

```
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("client_secret.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/drive-go-quickstart.json
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, drive.DriveMetadataReadonlyScope)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(ctx, config)

    srv, err := drive.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve drive Client %v", err)
    }

    r, err := srv.Files.List().PageSize(10).
        Fields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve files: %v", err)
    }

    // From here, it's sample script.
    searchfile := "filename"
    r, err := srv.Files.List().
        Q("name=\"" + searchfile + "\" and trashed=false").Fields("files(id,parents)").Do() // "trashed=false" doesn't search in the trash box.
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
    }
    for _, i := range r.Files {
        r, err := srv.Files.Get(i.Parents[0]).Fields("name").Do()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("FileID=%s, FolderID=%s, FolderName=%s\n", i.Id, i.Parents[0], r.Name)
    }
}
```

**Result :**

```
FileID=#####, FolderID=#####, FolderName=#####
```

Files on Google Drive can have several parent folders. At this script, it assumes that each file has one parent folder. If your files have several parent folders, please retrieve their folders from parent array.

**References :**

drive.files.list 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

drive.files.get 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get

Go Quickstart for Drive API 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/go